# Combine transformation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Question:

Find the transformation matrix that combines the following transformation matrices, in order:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 &3  &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &-1  &0  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &2  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0  &1 \\  
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 &\frac{\sqrt3}{2}  &0  &\frac{-1}{2}  &0 \\ 
 &0  &1  &0  &0 \\ 
 &\frac{1}{2}  &0  &\frac{\sqrt3}{2}  &0 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0  &1 \\  
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 &1  &0  &0  &3 \\ 
 &0  &1  &0  &-1 \\ 
 &0  &0  &1  &2 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0  &1 \\  
\end{bmatrix}$$

I know you are meant to multiply them together, and I get the same result online calculators get, but the answer in my textbook is:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 &\frac{3\sqrt3}{2}  &0  &-1  &3 \\ 
 &0  &-1  &0  &-1 \\ 
 &\frac{3}{2}  &0  &\sqrt3  &2 \\ 
 &0  &0  &0  &1 \\  
\end{bmatrix}$$

Am I missing something, how is this result achieved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: **order matters** in matrix multiplication, and particularly, consider the order in which the transformations are applied. If the matrices are named $A, B, C$ respectively, and operate on some matrix $Q$, which transformation matrix do you want apply first? Second? Lastly?

Comment: I know it matters, it says to do it in order, which is what I had done and received a different result than listed above.

Comment: Did you multiply $CBA$ or $ABC$? (A top, B middle, C last). A is applied first, so it is on the right, B is applied second, so it is in the middle, C is applied last, so it is on the left.

Comment: so it should be multiplied CBA? I understand now! Thanks once again.

Comment: You're welcome, Cypras!

Comment: @amWhy: Nice when you know they got it! +1

Comment: Column matrices and row matrices are concatenated in opposite orders to get the same result, IIRC. So it could be related(?)